# it is necessary to learn bootstrap before angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am newbie in Angular-js and wants to learn Angular-js effectively.i have not worked in Bootstrap before. Is it necessary to learn Bootstrap before learning Angular-js ??

Answer (score 1):

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is a HTML/CSS framework to play smartly with HTML and CSS and have 
best User experience.

Whereas, [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) is a javascript framework which handles your middle layer between HTMLs and Server Calls.

So to learn angular without bootstrap is not bad deal.

I hope i am clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all.  Bootstrap is one several styling libraries, which are quite optional.  But they do give you a way to get a great looking site with little effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you learn bootstrap it would help you to develop a website with bootstrap popups,modals etc without giving css guy a additional work , learning bootstrap is optional but if you leaarn u will become a good front end angular js developer